# Hide Site Action WSS 3.0 SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

I want to give a member a privilege to create a sub site or workspace with same permission as that of parent site. I have changed the OOTB "Contribute" permission level i.e. I have given permission to Create a web site. After doing this a Site Action Menu appear and I don't want it to be displayed when member with "Contribute" permission level is logged in. Is is possible to Hide Site Action at all without using designer?

Answer (score 3):

Why not just create a new permission set, lets call it "Site Creators", that has all the option checked that contribute has + create site. Then create a new SharePoint group, add your users and add the new permissions set to the group's permissions.

Comment: If I do this then it allows me to create a site with unique permission only under permissions section the radio button for "Use permission same as parent Site" disables I have no choice to select it but I want user to create a site with same permissions as parent site.

Answer (score 1):

Below are what I do usually. Hope it works for you too.

No.1 Open up the master page in SharePoint Designer. 

No.2 Wrap the html of the Site Actions within a SPSecurityTrimmedControl.

No.3 Set the Permissions String as appropriate.